# Peculiar behavior in a union data type when variables are getting initialized?

Tags: c, unions

When I initialize an integer first to that of a `float` in a union, then why does the value of the integer get changed? I have even tried interchanging by initializing `float` first to that of the integer but even then I get the value of the float to be zero.

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
union t{
    int x;
    float y;
} u;
int main()
{
    u.x = 2;
    printf("original value of integer: %d\n", u.x);
    printf("original address of integer: %p\n", u.x);
    u.y = 8.23;
    printf("value of float: %f\n", u.y);
    printf("address of float: %p\n", u.y);
    printf("after value of integer: %d\n", u.x);
    printf("after address value of integer: %p", u.x);
    return 0;
 }
```

[image: this is the image of the result of the above code]

Please can you explain this behavior?

Comment: `%p", u.x` is not an address, it's printing value (and it is _undefined behavior_). `why does the value of the integer gets changed?` Do you understand what an union is?

Comment: There is no initialization in the code shown; there are only assignments.

Comment: Don't post images of plain text.  Include the text in your question.  Format it as code — use triple-backquote followed by `none` to specify that the output should not be formatted for any particular language (and mark the end with another triple backquote line).

Comment: You can't just change a format specifier from `%d` to `%p` and expect it to magically take the address of the argument.  You need to do it explicitly, e.g. `&u.x`.  And strictly speaking, you should cast it to `void *`, e.g. `(void *)&u.x`.  Then you can use `%p`.

Comment: thank you, @TomKarzes  now I understood how the address should be printed. But can u pls explain why the value is getting changed?

Comment: @KamilCuk I didn't understand that's why I approached this forum

Comment: Sure. This forum is rather programming enthusiast that already know programming to ask about specific programming problems. It's not a good place to learn. I suggest you rather approach a [good C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: hey thanks, @KamilCuk for suggesting me this

Comment: @Rohit_Sharma `u.x` and `u.y` overlap in memory (that's what a `union` does).  So assigning to either one of them invalidates the value of the other.  If that's ok, then a `union` makes sense since it takes less memory than a `struct`.  If it doesn't, then you need to use a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` format specifier has to match the type of argument passed. `%p` expects a `void *` argument, passing `u.x` that has the type of `int` to it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)), and results on your implementation and architecture in printing the number in hex representation using upper case characters (as this is what usually `%p` uses). Ie. `0x4103AE14 = 1090760212`.

To print the address of a variable use [address of operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) and because the result of `&u.x` type is `int*` explicitly cast it to `void*` to match `%p` requirement:

```
printf("address of float: %p\n", (void*)&u.y);
printf("The address of u.x is: %p\n", (void*)&u.x);
```

Which will result in printing the same address.

> why does the value of the integer get changed?

Because they share the memory.

> Please can you explain this behavior?

Most probably your compiler uses [IEEE 745](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) to represent floating point numbers. The number `8.23` is most probably represented as a single precision floating point number `8.229999542236328125` that is encoded as
`0x4103AE14` (compare ex. with [this site](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=056046050051) or [this site](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)).

Because the floating point variable and integer variable share the memory in an `union` (and stars are in proper positions - on your platform `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`) the same bit representation of the `float` value is interpreted as an `int`. So when you access the `u.x` variable of that union, the bit representation of a `float` number encoded as `0x4103AE14` is interpreted as an `int`, which results in the number, well, `0x4103AE14` (because [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of float and int is same) which is equal to `1090760212` in dec.

Comment: oh okay now I get it, thanks for explaining me this